# query on 2.1.5 has cpu at 99 percent

Tags: neo4j, cypher

after executing the following query, the neo4j process takes 99% of the cpu until i kill it.

> match (p:L1)-[*3]-(t:L4) return t limit 1

However, this one comes back in a few milliseconds. ( i would expect them to return the same node )

> match (p:L1)-[:REL_1]-(c:L2)-[:REL_2]-(i:L3)-[:REF_3]-(t:L4) return *
>   limit 1

any light into my mistake would be greatly appreciated :)

the db is small one still.

- 8000   nodes
- 28800  relationships
- 50729  properties

Comment: Would you be able to share your graph? Please send it and your query to michael at neo4j.org

Answer (score 1):

Try using the experimental cypher compiler, like so:

```
cypher 2.1.experimental 
match (p:L1)-[*3]-(t:L4) 
return t 
limit 1
```

Comment: 5 minutes and it's still running. cpu is at 99 :/

Comment: is there some reason you can't use the better query?

Comment: there is no reason ( i plan to ) ,  i guess at this point i'd like to understand to which pit i have fallen into :)
Do i always have to construct explicit queries ?

Comment: the problem is that the lack of relationship direction and type makes it so that the number of possible paths is too high to find the :L4 end node. as an example, take off the :L4 Label and see if you get a result back.